# Flutter FirebaseFirestore imageUrl: permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, permission-denied

With my app, a user uploads image to firestore which later firebase database retrieves it. Everything works alright. The image is stored in firestore, the url link is accessed in database. However, when I copy the link to open in browser I get this error.

{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied."
}
}

Any reason why?

This is my code:

```
class ImageVerificationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageVerificationScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageVerificationScreen> createState() =>
      _ImageVerificationScreenState();
}

class _ImageVerificationScreenState extends State<ImageVerificationScreen> {
  File? image;
  String imageUrl = '';
  

  Future<File> customCompressed(
      {required File imagePathToCompress,
      quality = 100,
      percentage = 10}) async {
    var path = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
        imagePathToCompress.absolute.path,
        quality: 100,
        percentage: 80);
    return path;
  }

  Future<File?> pickImages(BuildContext context) async {
    File? image;
    try {
      final pickedImage =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (pickedImage != null) {
        image = File(pickedImage.path);
        File compressedImage =
            await customCompressed(imagePathToCompress: image);
        setState(() {
          image = compressedImage;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
    }

    return image;
  }

  void uploadImage() async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

    Reference refDirImage = ref.child('Documents');
    Reference refImageUpload = refDirImage.child(uid);

    try {
      await refImageUpload.putFile(File(image!.path));
      imageUrl = await refImageUpload.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (error) {
      return;
    }
  }

  Future<String?> documentID() async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    CollectionReference document =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    document.doc(uid).collection('Documents').add({'Document': imageUrl});
    return 'Documant uploaded';
  }

  // for selecting image
  void selectImage() async {
    image = await pickImages(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              size: 35,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight * 0.05,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Document',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => selectImage(),
              child: image == null
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                      width: screenWidth,
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                        size: 70,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: FileImage(image!),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),

                          // your own shape
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
            if (image == null)
              const Text(
                'Click on the camera icon above to the a photo',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight * 0.2,
            ),
            if (image != null)
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    uploadImage();
                    documentID();
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Upload document',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ))
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[subcollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGaoM.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+permission+denied?

Comment: So you seem to be using appspot, could you send the full image url? Does it work fine when accessing the image url from a browser itself?